# VS Studio - Method color gone to white after update to 16.6.0

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Well, after I updated my vs studio community 2019 to latest version 16.6.0, all my method color turn white.

I found **Tools > Options > Fonts and Colors > User Members - Methods** are able to change color, but I not sure the custom RGB color. I using dark theme, I remember the method color was kind a yellow.

If anyone know the RGB color for the method or there is other way to fix this, please leave your comment. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not completely sure but it was something like this:

R: 250

G: 238

B: 190

H: 32

S: 206

L: 207

Answer (score 7):

Go to **Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced**, then scroll down to "Editor Color Scheme", and change the selection to "**Visual Studio 2019**".

Comment: I think this should be THE answer!

Answer (score 1):

I went to **Debug > Options > Environment > General** and changed color theme to somthing else, pressed ok and changed it back, the default colors appeard again